# Rails i18n does not translate from yml the relation name on plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have this scenario, the `person` object has a`price`.

When I try to destroy the `price` that is being used by`person`, I can not because it is `dependent :: restrict_with_error`. (This is expected)

I use yml files to translate error messages from English to Portuguese. But the relationship in the plural is not translated.

**Relationship**
price has_many: people
person belongs_to: price

Example:

> obj_price.errors.messages: Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem ***people*** dependentes

I expected ***people*** to be translated to ***pessoas***

**price.rb**

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :people, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :price
end
```

**price.yml**

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    models:
      price: Tabela de Preços
      prices: Tabelas de Preços
    attributes:
      price:
        name: Nome
```

**person.yml**

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    models:
      person: Pessoa
      people: Pessoas
    attributes:
      person:
        id: ID
        name: Nome
        price_id: Tabela de preços
```

Comment: may be it help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised

Answer (score 2):

According to the [rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) you should use `one` for singular and `other` for plural.

So in your **person.yml**

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    models:
      person: 
        one: Pessoa
        other: Pessoas
    attributes:
      person:
        id: ID
        name: Nome
        price_id: Tabela de preços
```

Comment: Does not worked for me and I don't know why. I will create a new project and try again. Tks